# How to lower this image and background without creating a massive margin where nothing can be entered to?

Tags: html, css, image

Hi can anyone help me I'm trying to have this image and background in the center of my page but also down from the red bar I can only seem to do it with a massive margin which I can't put anything in, any advice would be appreciated thank you.

```
HTML:
<main>
    <img src="image/cup_coffee.png" alt="Cup of coffee with raw coffee beans around it" class="cup_coffee">
        <span>This is a text</span>
    </main>

CSS:
main{
background-color: #e6e6e6;
display: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%
```

[This is what it looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOHZ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a flex as a display instead of relative.

```css
.main {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).